# Let's get critical: Apr 2015 Site Self-Evaluation

Tags: discussion, site-evaluation

We all love [Astronomy Stack Exchange](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com), but there is a whole world of people out there who need answers to their questions and don't even know that this site exists. When they arrive from Google, what will their first impression be? Let's try to look at this site through the eyes of someone who's never seen it before, and see how we stack up against the rest of the 'Net.

The [Site Self-Evaluation review queue](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/review/site-eval) is open and populated with 10 questions that were asked and answered in the last quarter. 
Run a few Google searches to see how easy they are to find and compare the answers we have with the information available on other sites.

Rating the questions is only a part of the puzzle, though. Do you see a pattern of questions that should have been closed but are not? Questions or answers that could use an edit? Anything that's going really well? **Post an answer below to share your thoughts** and discuss these questions and the site's health with your fellow users!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

## Final Results

- [How much mass does an object in space need to keep a human on its surface?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/8752/how-much-mass-does-an-object-in-space-need-to-keep-a-human-on-its-surface)

**Net Score: 8** (Excellent: 8, Satisfactory: 2, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [How can we tell that a short-period binary is tidally locked?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/10012/how-can-we-tell-that-a-short-period-binary-is-tidally-locked)

**Net Score: 7** (Excellent: 7, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 0)

---

- [Could a close passing star be captured by the Sun's gravity?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/9934/could-a-close-passing-star-be-captured-by-the-suns-gravity)

**Net Score: 4** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [How can a galaxy in-between our view and the galaxy behind it have a 'lensing effect'?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/10036/how-can-a-galaxy-in-between-our-view-and-the-galaxy-behind-it-have-a-lensing-ef)

**Net Score: 3** (Excellent: 5, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 2)

---

- [Can planets inside the Earth's orbit around the Sun appear to undergo retrograde motion?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/9924/can-planets-inside-the-earths-orbit-around-the-sun-appear-to-undergo-retrograde)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 6, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Does one need to take into account finite gravity speed in N-body simulations?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/8789/does-one-need-to-take-into-account-finite-gravity-speed-in-n-body-simulations)

**Net Score: 2** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 1)

---

- [Does the cosmic microwave background recede at the speed of light?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/8764/does-the-cosmic-microwave-background-recede-at-the-speed-of-light)

**Net Score: 0** (Excellent: 3, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Would a killer asteroid shattered into thousands of pieces produce the same devastation?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/9926/would-a-killer-asteroid-shattered-into-thousands-of-pieces-produce-the-same-deva)

**Net Score: -2** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 5, Needs Improvement: 3)

---

- [Hubble HST scheduling algorithm](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/8805/hubble-hst-scheduling-algorithm)

**Net Score: -3** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 3, Needs Improvement: 4)

---

- [What uncertainty does an error bar signify in astronomy?](https://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/8841/what-uncertainty-does-an-error-bar-signify-in-astronomy)

**Net Score: -4** (Excellent: 1, Satisfactory: 4, Needs Improvement: 5)

---